# `ant` is looking for `aapt` in project directory?

Tags: android, ant, build, aapt

I am lately having problems with a build process that has been working for months now - I may have updated the Android build tools since the last working build, but I am not sure.

In any case

```
ant -Dsdk.dir=$ANDROID_HOME -Djava.source=7 -Djava.target=7 clean release
```

is failing with the following message:

```
/home/dmta/development/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:694: Execute failed: java.io.IOException:
Cannot run program "/home/dmta/EclipseProjects/MyProject/Hawk/${aapt}"
(in directory "/home/dmta/EclipseProjects/MyProject/Hawk"): error=2,
No such file or directory
```

Where Hawk is a library project I am using.

What could be wrong here?

I can build the program from Eclipse but I need to use the ant build for proguard.

Answer (score 1):

the AAPt location is changed in the latest update. Copy the lib/dx and aapt : these two files back to platform-tools.
Also try adding the tools path if not there already, example:

```
<!-- tools location -->
<property name="android.tools.dir" location="${sdk.dir}/tools" />
<property name="android.platform.tools.dir" location="${sdk.dir}/platform-tools" />
<property name="android.buildtools.dir" location="${sdk.dir}/build-tools/22.0.1" />
<condition property="exe" value=".exe" else="">    <os family="windows" />    </condition>
<condition property="bat" value=".bat" else="">    <os family="windows" />    </condition>
<property name="adb" location="${android.platform.tools.dir}/adb${exe}" />
<property name="lint" location="${android.tools.dir}/lint${bat}" />
<property name="zipalign" location="${android.buildtools.dir}/zipalign${exe}" />
<property name="aidl" location="${android.platform.tools.dir}/aidl${exe}" />
<property name="aapt" location="${android.buildtools.dir}/aapt${exe}" />
<property name="dx" location="${android.buildtools.dir}/dx${bat}" />
<property name="renderscript" location="${android.buildtools.dir}/llvm-rs-cc${exe}"/>
<property name="lint" location="${android.tools.dir}/lint${bat}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure which files I should copy exactly from where to where. My SDK stuff is in `~/development/android-sdk-linux/`, i. e. that is where a folder called `platform-tools` is located. But where would the old version be?

Comment: Also, what XML file is that you are showing - the build.xml of my project or the build.xml in `    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />` that's imported by all the other ones?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of S P's initial answer I was able to get this to work.

It is worth noting that my question, or at least the question title is misleading: At first I thought that ant was actually looking for the executable `aapt` inside the project folder.

However, on closer inspection it actually is looking for `${aapt}`. This indicates that ant is trying to use the value of a property called "aapt", which is however not set. So instead of building any sensible executable path it just appends the name to it's current working directory - or something like that.

In any case, all I needed to to was insert the following lines into my `~/development/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml` file:

```
<property name="android.buildtools.dir" location="${sdk.dir}/build-tools/22.0.1" />
<property name="aapt" location="${android.buildtools.dir}/aapt" />
<property name="aidl" location="${android.buildtools.dir}/aidl" />
<property name="dx" location="${android.buildtools.dir}/dx" />
<property name="zipalign" location="${android.buildtools.dir}/zipalign" />
```

That's because as soon as I told ant where to find `aapt` it complained about `aidl`, `dx` and `zipalign`.